# JW Player not autostarting in a colorbox modal in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, colorbox, jwplayer

I'm having problems getting JW Player to autostart videos that are in a colorbox modal in any Internet Explorer browser. It appears that the player does indeed load as a black box displays with the JW Player watermark. Also, the watermark fades away as if it thinks its playing the video, however, it just displays a black block. Seems as if the video file isn't loading properly

Any help would be greatly appreciated, many thanks in advance.

Sample Code of colorbox HTML content:

```
<!-- This contains the hidden content for inline calls -->
<div style='display:none'>

<div id='resRemote' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
 <h1>Remote Monitoring</h1>
 <object width="368" height="207" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="swf/player.swf" id="player_resRemote">
  <param name="movie" value="swf/player.swf" />
  <param name="flashvars" value="file=/videos/remote.flv&amp;controlbar=none&amp;autostart=true" />
 </object>
</div>

</div>
```

Sample Code of colorbox js content:

```
$(".resRemote").colorbox({width:"450px", inline:true, href:"#resRemote"});
```

Comment: The only time you should see a black box is if the player hasn't correctly understood how to load your file. Can you please post some sample embed code or a link?

Comment: thanks for the reply zach, i have added some code. as I mentioned above, it autoplays in FF and chrome but not IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer here is not straight forward given that this is working in FF / Chrome and not IE. Here are the steps I'd take to try and fix this:

1. Get a proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and make sure that your requests from IE are going to the same place as your requests in FF / Chrome. I can't imagine they'd be different, but if they are, you'll need to alter your embed code to reflect that.
2. Using a <object> tag by itself isn't a great way to go. Instead, try using [SWFObject or <object> / <embed>](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/13/embedding-flash). If you want to quickly generate new embed code, check out [LongTail's setup wizard](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard).
3. Try grabbing the most recent version of the player. There may have been a bug fix that resolved this issue.

Again, I'm sorry that I can't provide a more direct answer - it's just not clear that you've done anything incorrectly.

Best,

Zach

Developer, LongTail Video